# init_color and wbkgd to show colored window

Tags: c, function, colors, ncurses

following is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ncurses.h>
void main()
{
    initscr();
    if(has_colors() == FALSE && COLORS == 256 && can_change_color() == FALSE)
    {   
        endwin();
        printf("Your terminal does not support color\n");
        goto end;
    }
    start_color();
    init_color(1,113,121,126);
    wbkgd(stdscr,???);
    getch();
    endwin();
end:
}
```

I want to color stdscr window using color from the `init_color` line but I can't find any related function to be used in `wbkgd()` as the 2nd argument.
Can anyone tell me the right function to be used in order to achieve the above goal.

Answer (score 0):

[`wbkgd`](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_bkgd.3x.html#h3-bkgd) uses a `chtype` parameter.  A `chtype` consists of a character with an optional attribute.  A `COLOR_PAIR` is an attribute.

However -

If you are really trying to use the given **RGB** values, that will not work with `init_color`: the color pair is an *index* into a *palette* of colors.

Rather than *indexed* color, you appear to be attempting use *direct* color. With ncurses 6.1, you can use RGB values, mapping those (with a suitable terminal description such as [xterm-direct](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-xterm-direct), which has the RGB capability described in the **[user_caps](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/user_caps.5.html)** manual page) mapped onto the range `0` to `0x1000000`.

The [***`picsmap`***](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-slang.html#compare_picsmap) program (in [ncurses-examples](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-examples.html)) illustrates how to set up the colors.

To set the *background* using extended colors, you would have to use [**`wbkgrnd`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_bkgrnd.3x.html#h3-bkgrnd), which uses a complex character `cchar_t`.  The color pair in *that* structure could be set using the *`opts`* parameter of **`setcchar`**, as described in the [Extensions](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getcchar.3x.html#h2-EXTENSIONS) section of the manual page.

Comment: `wbkgd` doesn't care how the color was defined: it uses just a color-pair.  That is also true for the wide-character version `wbkgrnd`.  Without a complete program ([MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), there's no more specific help available.